# Notation reading

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Recently, I have been accepted in an undergrad physics degree in Germany. However, I have been having trouble reading notation because I studied in a high school outside of Europe. The notation I am having trouble with are the colons that read in the following problem.

Noah, Hassan and Zhang want to rent a $60 \ \text{m}^{2}$ apartment together as a shared flat. The apartment costs $11.50$ per $\text{m}^{2}$. How much does everyone must pay if their shares are like $2:2.5:3$?

I understand colons represent ratios, but what is the right interpretation of them in the problem's context assuming you might want to rewrite them as a fraction like $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Let $x$ denote the amount that $N$ pays.  Then $H$ pays $\frac {2.5}2\times x$ and so on.  The sum must be the total cost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every \$2 Noah pays, Hassan pays \$2.50 and Zhang pays \$3.

Comment: @paul: Alternatively, you can change "Noah share : Hassan share : Zhang share EQUALS $2:2.5:3$" to "for some constant $k$ we have Noah share $=2k$ and Hassan share $=2.5k$ and Zhang share $= 3k$", and then make use of these specific values in terms of $k.$ Depending on the problem, you'll either find the value of $k$ and then answer the question asked, or in trying to answer the question the value of $k$ drops out. For this particular problem you'll be able to find the value of $k.$ If the problem had asked for a ratio of certain quantities, then the value of $k$ will often drop out.

Comment: If you study in Germany-my home- it is very usual to ask an other student the meaning of an expression , when more than one dos not know, ask the professor .#